# Stop Visual Studio from adding using statements

Tags: visual-studio

It appears that Visual Studio 2019 is adding using statements when I do not intend for it to.  While I do really like the right-click Quick Action to add a missing using, I do not want it happening when I do not ask for it.

It's hard to track down when this happens as I'm often typing quickly and only later on do I notice the new using.

Comment: I wonder if this is really VS.  What extensions do you have installed?  I would start there.

Comment: Found the awnser here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61811825/stop-vs-from-automatically-adding-using-directives
"Found the fix. Under Tools > Options... > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense, I had to uncheck 'Show items from unimported namespaces (experimental)'."