# Stop VS from automatically adding using directives

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

I don't mind the using directives which are automatically created when the script is created. Those are fine. What I'm talking about are the using directives which are *automatically generated* at the top of the script while I'm coding as soon as I refer to a type which is out of scope. A pox upon the silent fiends!

To clarify, currently if I try including a type which exists in some namespace which is not yet declared as 'using' in the script, said namespace will get auto-added to the top of the script. This is undesired behavior for me.

I simply prefer to manually add my namespaces.

Comment: No it does not. If I type something not in scope I get a little light buld which allows be to add the missing `using` (such as `using System.Linq;`) or to use the full type (such as `System.Linq.Enumerable`).

Comment: Also the "right" terminology here is, [*using directive*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with "script"? What type of script, what language?

Comment: Perhaps it's due to an extension. I don't have many, but the ones which seem like potential culprits are 'Visual Studio 2019 Tools for Unity' and 'Visual Studio IntelliCode'.. I'm using Unity and Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.5.4. By "script", I mean a C# script in a Unity project.

Comment: I ruled out those extensions as the problem. Disabling them did not stop the automatic generation behavior for using directives.

Comment: Also, I've verified that the automatic generation behavior happens even in non-Unity projects. For example, it will occur in a console app project.

Comment: This feature has, multiple times now, silently added in some using directives from weird namespaces, causing me obscure nonsensical build errors. It takes me a while to track down what happened. That's so much worse than having to right click and add one. I think we can safely conclude that this "experimental feature" is a dud, and should be turned off by default in the next update of Visual Studio.

Comment: Since this was the top result on google, here's the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74128506/prevent-visual-studio-from-auto-import-namespace-when-copy-paste

Answer (score 48):

On the top of the page in Visual Studio, go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Uncheck the option for "Add missing using directives on paste" then click OK on the bottom of the page. And then restart Visual Studio.

Answer was originally posted (much better) here, but posted here since this is the top google result and didn't have the answer:

[Prevent Visual Studio from auto import namespace when copy paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74128506/prevent-visual-studio-from-auto-import-namespace-when-copy-paste)

Comment: The location has changed (Feb 2023), but searching for "Add missing using directives on paste" will let you find it quickly.

Answer (score 16):

Under Tools > Options... > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense, uncheck 'Show items from unimported namespaces (experimental)'.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. I only wish Microsoft would add an option to still show results from unimported namespaces but add the namespace when autocompleting instead of a `using`.

Comment: Didn't work for me as of with Version 17.4.3. It still adds using when i copy/paste code. Such a shame and unprofessional of MSFT.

Comment: @edwabr123 there is a separate feature for doing this when pasting in Visual Studio 17.4.4 [Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Advanced->Add missing using directives on paste]

Comment: This is right answer for non the pasting cases, but it's needed to restart VS after changing it to take effect. Thanks @nate-h.

Comment: @PatrickV I have this option turned off and it still inserts usings everywhere

Answer (score 14):

In Visual Studio 2022, The option to stop VS from automatically importing the directories on paste has been moved under **tools -> options -> text editor -> C# -> advanced**. From here you could deselect the option. It is selected by default. Quite annoying ! Posting screenshot for reference :
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Even I find this annoying. I was able to turn this off in VS 2022 using the following options. Hope this helps some one.

I do agree that Microsoft should give us an option to list the items from unimported namespaces but not add using statements automatically.

[image]