# Prevent Visual Studio from auto import namespace when copy paste

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, namespaces

I am using Visual Studio with Unity. When I copy and paste a code in Visual Studio. It automatically adds an unnecessary namespace on the top. It is pretty annoying to see if there have many unused namespaces over time. May I ask if is this a bug or how can I turn off the auto import namespace when copy paste?

From the suggested name, I think Visual Studio confuses the "length" and "Length"
[image]

Here are the steps to reproduce the problem

[image]

Comment: Probably because the code doesnt compile and its trying to be helpful in a way only computers can.   If you defined length and then hit paste does it quit being annoying?

Comment: @Yiming You should disable "Enable namespace update when moving files" in Visual Studio. But I can't find this option in the 2022 version!

Comment: Paste with the defined variable will not import the namespace. But I want to define the variable after work manually. There always have code with multiple variables that I cannot guarantee they all have defined.

Comment: In the C# editor options, under Advanced, Using Directives, uncheck "Add missing using directives on paste".

Comment: @madreflection it would be great if you made that comment into an answer!

Comment: C# editor checked "Add missing usage directives when pasting". as madreflection
said

Answer (score 29, accepted):

On the top of the page in Visual Studio, go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Uncheck the option for "Add missing using directives on paste" then click OK on the bottom of the page. **And then restart Visual Studio**.

Might be useful to some to note that tab completion will still auto-add missing using directives.

[image]

Here is an example with the option checked (the example specifics are not relevant but in this case an attribute is being pasted to an ASP.Net Core Razor Page):
[image: Checked Option]

Here is an example with the option unchecked:
[image: Unchecked option]

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed. Visual Studio has been auto-including the wrong choice of ambiguous classes too much on my latest project.