# Stop Visual Studio from adding using statements (Visual Studio 2022 edition)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, using

This question comes up a lot, is there any way to get Microsoft's attention and convince them to stop inserting this extremely annoying feature?

If I have a C# file that doesn't currently use System.Collections.Generic, and I type a line like this:

```
List<string> moose = new();
```

VS then happily inserts

```
using iTextSharp.text;
```

which is of course completely wrong.

I swear it's like Clippy all over again but without checking before making any changes.

There is an option in the Tools menu that [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61811825/stop-vs-from-automatically-adding-using-directives) say should control this feature, but apparently Microsoft left the option in but ignores the value (although to be fair I'm not pasting anything):

[image]

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74128506/prevent-visual-studio-from-auto-import-namespace-when-copy-paste) that does say "tab completion will still auto-add missing using directives" but in my case I'm not tab-completing.  I'm just typing in the line of code.

Has anyone found a way to disable this "feature"?

Comment: Yeah it's been annoyingly off for a couple of months already. For me it's been auto-importing `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2019.Drawing` namespace every time I type something like `Model` (`Model3D` lives in that namespace).

Comment: _is there any way to get Microsoft's attention_: [Report a problem with the Visual Studio product or installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022), [Developer Community guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/developer-community-guidelines?WT.mc_id=visualstudio_community_aka_vsfeedbackguidelines&view=vs-2022), and [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home)

Comment: The following may (or may not) be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70097398/10024425

Comment: @user09938 a yes the developer community, where 250 questions a day get posted and zero answered. Welcome to customer support in 2015+.

Comment: @CodeCaster: What exactly do you mean by _answered_? I received a response to both of my questions: _Needs more information_ and/or _the issue is not reproducible and will be closed within 14 days_ -- even though I included the steps necessary to reproduce the issue, Obviously not a _solution_, but some may consider a _response_ to be an _answer_.  Additionally, some may consider a lack of response an answer as well. I imagine that occassionally they select a question to try to find a solution to. Who knows, maybe one will win the _question lottery_ and someone will offer a solution.

Comment: Hello, I am sorry that according to your instructions, I added List<string> moose = new(); to the console project of Visual Studio 2022, and did not automatically insert using iTextSharp.text;.
But try to use this workaround. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63021857

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT - that'd be because a new console project in VS 2022 will be using global usings and `System.Collections.Generic` is in there so no `using` needs to be inserted at all. You'd see differently if you disabled global usings in the project.

Answer (score 6):

I followed the "report a problem with VS" link and got a response within about a day!  Their initial answer was that the "Show items from unimported namespaces" option does what I want.  Unchecking that did indeed disable the insertion of the 'using' statement.

I did submit a follow-up bug asking that they fix the text of the option, as "show items from unimported namespaces" does not at all indicate "and add using statements".

[image]

Comment: You can see the entire bug report, and their fix that actually worked, here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/67372

Comment: "Show items from unimported namespaces" is actually useful. The problem is "Default IntelliSense completion mode: Automatic" and should be changed to "Tab-only"